# groupbox not becoming visible

Tags: vb.net, groupbox

I'm having a problem getting a second GroupBox visible, this is my code

```
        Me.grpCallerDetails.Location = New Point(x:=0, y:=2000)
        Me.grpCallerDetails.Visible = False
        Me.grpCallDuration.Location = New Point(x:=0, y:=0)
        Me.grpCallDuration.BringToFront()
        Me.grpCallDuration.Visible = True
        Me.Refresh()
```

the grpCallDuration.Visible property remains False even after setting the property to True.

Initially the settings are:

```
        Me.grpCallerDetails.Location = New Point(x:=0, y:=0)
        Me.grpCallerDetails.Visible  = True
        Me.grpCallDuration.Location = New Point(x:=2000, y:=0)
        Me.grpCallDuration.Visible = False
```

I'm moving the location of the group boxes around so that they don't overlap, but nothing, so far is working.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it.

The problem was grpCallerDetails was Docked Fill, and grpCallDuration remained as a child of that GroupBox no matter what I did.

I just changed the Dock to None and moved grpCallDuration out on its own...